# Can't Assign Struct Equal to Struct from another Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im working on player movement coding, and I want to have premade movement stats prepared for "Power ups" and so forth. I made a stats management script separate from my movement script for the sake of organization and I have the movement variables packed in structs so that they can be switched out during Play Mode.

I can import the Outgoing Stats struct from the stats management script, but I want to assign the struct to its own variable in the movement script so that its easier to handle. It does copy but my new struct variable returns 0 on all of its internal variables instead of copying the values from the original struct.

Tl;dr Im trying to copy a struct from one script to the other but when said struct copies, the copy has variables with 0.

Stats Management Script

```
public struct StatsSet
{
    public int JumpCount;
    public float JumpPower;
    public float MoveSpeed;
    public float QuickFallMultiplier;
    public float BaseFallMultiplier;
}

//Public variables for experimental movement stats testing
public int ExJumpCount = 1;
public float ExJumpPower = 6.0f;
public float ExMoveSpeed = 4.0f;
public float ExQuickFallMultiplier = 2.0f;
public float ExBaseFallMultiplier = 2.5f;

public int Statpick = 1;
public StatsSet StatsOut;
private StatsSet ExStats;
private StatsSet BaseStats;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    BaseStats.JumpCount = 1;
    BaseStats.JumpPower = 6.0f;
    BaseStats.MoveSpeed = 4.0f;
    BaseStats.QuickFallMultiplier = 2.0f;
    BaseStats.BaseFallMultiplier = 2.5f;

    ExStats.BaseFallMultiplier = ExBaseFallMultiplier;
    ExStats.JumpCount = ExJumpCount;
    ExStats.JumpPower = ExJumpPower;
    ExStats.MoveSpeed = ExMoveSpeed;
    ExStats.QuickFallMultiplier = ExQuickFallMultiplier;
    Statpick = 1;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Statpick == 0)
    {
        StatsOut = ExStats;
    }
    else if (Statpick == 1)
    {
        StatsOut = BaseStats;
    }
}
```

Movement Script

```
private Rigidbody PlayerRigid;
private int JumpCheck;
private bool IsGrounded = true;
public Collider GroundCollider;
private int HiddenJumpCount;

//Import of player stats data
private PlayerStats PStats;
private PlayerStats.StatsSet PlayerStats;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    PStats = GetComponent<PlayerStats>();
    PlayerRigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    PlayerStats = PStats.StatsOut;
    JumpCheck = PlayerStats.JumpCount;
    Debug.Log("Up and running...");
}
```

PStats.Out returns the values Im expecting, but PlayerStats returns what seems to be null values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These scripts are both using `Start()` so my guess is that `MovementScript.Start()` is happening first and when it grabs the struct, it's grabbing a `default(StatsSet)` because your Stats Management Script hasn't initialized it yet.  You can throw a `Debug.Log()` into each to confirm that's your issue but here's how to fix it:

One option is to rename `Start()` to `Awake()` in your Stats Management Script.  You can learn more about Awake vs Start in [this video](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/awake-and-start) but TL;DR, all active scripts run their `Awake()` *then* all scripts run their `Start()`.

Your other option is to change the "Script Execution Order".  If you don't touch the [Script Execution Order Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html), the order of different `Start()` functions will be unknown.  You can use that settings menu to instead ensure your Stats Management Script *always* executes before your Movement Script by giving it an explicit execution order.

Comment: Editing the Script Execution Order seems to have fixed the issue. Thank you!

Comment: @ValueChip Don't forget to accept an answer by clicking the checkmark symbol next to it - this marks the question as solved to anyone else who comes across this question.